# Errors when running the Telnet_Login Module for Metasplot

Tags: authentication, telnet, metasploit

I am trying to telnet into a VLE (virtual lab environment) for a project, but I keep running into the same errors.
Each time I try to run the module, I get a "The following options failed to validate: USER_FILE, PASS_FILE.

I followed the steps verbatim with the link below from Offensive Security.
I also tried setting the IP to a single IP and not the "/24" option. Both failed.
I also tried using the path to the desktop, and also the way that the captures text shows.

https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/scanner-telnet-auxiliary-modules/

The system should force a telnet connection and capture the user name and password.

Results:

Auxiliary failed: Msf::OptionValidateError The following options failed to validate: USER_FILE, PASS_FILE.

#### Metasploit version

4.16.18-dev-5cdd364

### Additional Information

unable to update as this is a virtual machine provided by my university for running labs.

msf auxiliary(telnet_login) > show options

Module options (auxiliary/scanner/telnet/telnet_login):

Name              Current Setting   Required  Description

---

BLANK_PASSWORDS   false             no        Try blank passwords for all users
BRUTEFORCE_SPEED  5                 yes       How fast to bruteforce, from 0 to 5
DB_ALL_CREDS      false             no        Try each user/password couple stored in the      current database
DB_ALL_PASS       false             no        Add all passwords in the current database to the list
DB_ALL_USERS      false             no        Add all users in the current database to the  list
PASSWORD                            no        A specific password to authenticate with
PASS_FILE         passwords.txt     no        File containing passwords, one per line
RHOSTS            10.139.46.121/24  yes       The target address range or CIDR identifier
RPORT             23                yes       The target port (TCP)
STOP_ON_SUCCESS   false             yes       Stop guessing when a credential works for a  host
THREADS           254               yes       The number of concurrent threads
USERNAME                            no        A specific username to authenticate as
USERPASS_FILE                       no        File containing users and passwords separated  by space, one pair per line
USER_AS_PASS      false             no        Try the username as the password for all users
USER_FILE         users.txt         no        File containing usernames, one per line
VERBOSE           false             yes       Whether to print output for all attempts

```
msf auxiliary(telnet_login) > set USER_FILE users.txt
USER_FILE => users.txt
msf auxiliary(telnet_login) > set RHOSTS 10.139.46.121
RHOSTS => 10.139.46.121
msf auxiliary(telnet_login) > set PASS_FILE passwords.txt
PASS_FILE => passwords.txt
msf auxiliary(telnet_login) > run
[-] Auxiliary failed: Msf::OptionValidateError The following options failed to validate:      USER_FILE, PASS_FILE.
msf auxiliary(telnet_login) >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `unset USER_FILE` and all that. Maybe you have bad data in there.

Comment: I did the 'unset' for both of the ***_FILE and then did a run (just to make sure that everything else was flowing. Of course it said that the creds cannot be blank, then I set both the PASS and USER, the run command produced the same errors as before.

Comment: You can fill only required fields. USER and PASS are not required. Also, make sure the files are in your working directory. You can give full path like /home/USERNAME/Desktop/USER_FILE